# PIL image size adjustment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I want to repeat the drawing made in matplotlib in PIL. Perhaps the problem is that my data format is "4.005,4.006". How to make the same graph in PIL?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
N = 461
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x)
y=y+50
im = Image.new('L', (N, N))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    draw.line((x[i],y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1]),fill='red',width=2)
im.show()
# this is the graphic i want to get
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is syntactically correct,except for the fact that the x,y used to draw the lines are not coordinates of the canvas. They are values of a sinusoid.
You have to make some manipulations to x,y to make them appear in the Image.

Comment: @MSS What manipulations would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your x,y values need some shifting and magnification to somewhat resemble matplotlibs plot. I am not very good in plotting. This is what I could do. You can fine tune further.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
N = 300
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)*200
y = np.sin(x)*200+250
im = Image.new('RGB', (500, 500), color=(255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    draw.line((x[i],y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1]),fill='red',width=1)
im.show()
```